# What is the problem while saving flutter code

Tags: flutter

Good evening everyone I have a problem if I modify the code on android studio the changes do not appear on my emulator unless I restart android studio

Comment: VSCode has "hot reload on save" in the flutter extension.  I'd presume AS has a similar option.

Comment: Yea that's because you need to `Ctrl + S` to get it saved. It does when you exit the IDE

Comment: yes i do that but there is no change

Answer (score 0):

You need to "deliver" your code to a device. From Android Studio, you can click on `Flutter Hot Reload` (Flash icon on screenshot), or do this action by shortcut (depends on OS on your computer, put mouse cursor to `Flutter Hot Reload` icon and IDE give hint about hot key for this action): `Ctrl + Shift + \` on Windows or `Shift + \` on macOS.

[image]

Comment: You need to run app from IDE and don't close. Can you describe how do you do with app?